True or False about sequences and their limits
Decide if the following statements are true or false.
If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\{a_n\}} = +\infty$ and $b_n > 0$ for all n, therefore $\{a_n.b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ approaches $+\infty$ or converges.
I am struggling with this because I don't know if it is true or false:
On the one hand, I know that one indeterminate form in limits is $0 \cdot \infty$, because, for example, if you have $(a_n) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, which converges to zero, and $(b_n) = (n)$, which diverges to $\infty$, then the limit of $(a_n b_n)$ is 1. But if you have $(b_n) = n^2$, the limit of $(a_n b_n)$ doesn't exist because it diverges to $+\infty$.
So, I think because $0 \cdot \infty$ is an indeterminate form, the statement might be false, but I can't find a counterexample for it. For that reason, I tried to prove that it is true, but I'm struggling with the proof:
Because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\{a_n b_n\}} = \infty$ $\iff$ $\forall M > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n$, if $n > N \Rightarrow a_n b_n > M$
And $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\{a_n b_n\}} = l$ (that is ${a_n b_n}$ converges) $\iff$ $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n$ if $n > N \Rightarrow |a_n b_n - l| < \epsilon$
My problem is I don't know when to apply each definition, that is, for what classes of sequences ${\{a_n\}}$ and ${\{b_n\}}$ it holds that ${\{a_n b_n\}}$ converges or diverges to $\infty$, in the case that the statement is true.
Can you help me? Thank you :)

You already have an example of $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n b_n \to 1$, as well as an example of $b_n$ such that $a_n b_n \to \infty$. What happens if you let $b_n$ be the interlacing of these two sequences? That is, $1, 1^2, 2, 2^2, 3, 3^2, \ldots$?

WLOG $a_n>0$ for all $n$. What happens if you take $(c_n)$ to be any positive sequence whatsoever, and define $b_n = c_n/a_n$?

Did you mean to write "If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{{a_n}} = +\infty$ and $b_n > 0$ for all n, therefore ${a_n\color{red}{b_n}}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ approaches $+\infty$ or converges."?
